# How to load this class (static/non-static method)?

Tags: php, oop, class, static, constructor

At the beginning I had 3 PHP files to handle 3 different AJAX queries.

I've decided to create a unique PHP class where I'm getting $_POST parameters and then call 1 of the 3 functions.

I have another PHP class for database queries only (base.php). I'm including this file in my class used to get AJAX queries (ajax.php) and in my index.php file.

To begin I have written something like this (ajax.php):

```
<?php
    new Ajax();

    class Ajax
    {
        private $base;

        public function __construct()
        {
            include("base.php");
            $this->base = new Base();

            $script = $_POST["script"];

            $reference = $_POST["reference"];

            if($script == "correct" || $script == "insert") {
                $ptGauche = json_decode($_POST["repGauche"]);
                $ptDroite = json_decode($_POST["repDroite"]);
            }
            if($script == "insert") {
                $txtGauche = json_decode($_POST["motGauche"]);
                $txtDroite = json_decode($_POST["motDroite"]);
            }

            switch($script)
            {
                case "correct":
                    $this->correct($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite);
                    break;
                case "insert":
                    $this->insert($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite, $txtGauche, $txtDroite);
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    $this->delete($reference);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function correct($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite)
        {
            // code
            $query_result = $this->base->selectAllQuery($reference);
        }

        private function insert($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite, $txtGauche, $txtDroite)
        {
            //code
            $this->base->insertQuery($reference, $txtGauche, $txtDroite, $new_ptGauche, $new_ptDroite);
        }

        private function delete($reference)
        {
            //code
            $this->base->deleteQuery($reference);
        }
    }
?>
```

Apparently, it's not a good idea to do `new Ajax();` and not saving class instance in a variable like `$ajax = new Ajax();` [Class instance without variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119251/class-instance-without-variable)
Some say it's not standard to put code with side effect in class constructor `__construct` and maybe I should use static methods instead of creating an object with constructor and do something like `Ajax::functionToLoad();`.

This will just not work for my script because I'm using a non-static class included in this one, so my property `private $base;` should be non-static and it will be impossible to do database queries because "static functions can't access non-static properties" :/ http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/can-static-function-access-non-static-members-of-class/

So, I'm using non-static methods and instead of using a constructor I'm doing this:

```
$ajax = new Ajax();
$ajax->loader();

class Ajax
{
    private $base;

    public function loader()
    {
        // code
    }

    // correct(), insert() and delete() functions
}
```

Is it ok to do this or should I do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

public function Ajax()....    is the default constructor if __construct is not present. So use Ajax instead of loader OR create a function Ajax that does $this->loader();

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, isn't function Ajax() the same as __construct? Why should I use Ajax() instead of __constuct if they are both constructors?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a Singleton

```
 <?php
class Ajax
{
    private static $inst = new Ajax();

    private $base;

    public static function getInstance(){
         return $inst;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        include("base.php");
        $this->base = new Base();

        $script = $_POST["script"];

        $reference = $_POST["reference"];

        if($script == "correct" || $script == "insert") {
            $ptGauche = json_decode($_POST["repGauche"]);
            $ptDroite = json_decode($_POST["repDroite"]);
        }
        if($script == "insert") {
            $txtGauche = json_decode($_POST["motGauche"]);
            $txtDroite = json_decode($_POST["motDroite"]);
        }

        switch($script)
        {
            case "correct":
                $this->correct($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite);
                break;
            case "insert":
                $this->insert($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite, $txtGauche, $txtDroite);
                break;
            case "delete":
                $this->delete($reference);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function correct($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite)
    {
        // code
        $query_result = $this->base->selectAllQuery($reference);
    }

    private function insert($reference, $ptGauche, $ptDroite, $txtGauche, $txtDroite)
    {
        //code
        $this->base->insertQuery($reference, $txtGauche, $txtDroite, $new_ptGauche, $new_ptDroite);
    }

    private function delete($reference)
    {
        //code
        $this->base->deleteQuery($reference);
    }
}
?>
```

You should now be able to access the instance as follows

```
 <?php
      $defaultInst = Ajax::getInstance();
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't precise it  but it's a class used for AJAX queries only so I don't need to use class instance, here $defaultInst, outside the class